# How do I remove an element in a list at a specific index using a variable in Python?

Tags: python, list

My program uses this variable:

```
questionNum = random.randint(0,9)
```

Later in the program I tried to remove an element in the list by doing this:

```
questionList.remove([questionNum])
```

I got this error:

> list.remove(x): x not in list

How can I remove an element in the list at the index `questionNum`?

Comment: `list.remove(x)` searches for values, not indexes. `list.pop(index)` would do what you want. It's in the documentation.

Comment: Just as an FYI, a Google search with exactly the title of your question yielded some very good answers to this question. Please try searching before asking.

Answer (score 2):

`list.remove` takes the element to remove, not the index. `list.pop` is what you want.

Be aware, though, that this **decreases** your list's size. So, if you pop the element at index 5, elements at index 6, 7, 8 etc are now in index 5, 6, 7 etc.